# Unknown AWS APIClientException Cause

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm in the early stages of developing an AWS-enabled mobile app (VERY noivce level android developer - this is for a senior class project). I'm using a custom-generated SDK called RecoveryAsAService. I have the manifest permissions set but when I reach my factory.build(), the following exception is thrown:

```
Method threw 'com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientException' exception. Cannot evaluate $Proxy1.toString()
```

On line:

```
final RecoveryAsAServiceClient client = factory.build(RecoveryAsAServiceClient.class);
```

From all the documentation on this site and AWS and their forums, I cannot root cause the error for my particular case. Does anyone know what causes this error? Is it with establishing a connection? Or accessing my AWS server? Any and all insight would help.

All of my permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'app/libs')
```

Using .jar files:

aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core-2.7.2.jar

aws-android-sdk-core-2.7.2.jar

aws-apigateway-api-sdk-2.0.0.jar

My Activity Code:

```
           AWSCredentialsProvider credenetialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    getApplicationContext(),          // activity context
                    "COGNITO IDENTITY POOL ID", // Cognito identity pool id
                    Regions.US_WEST_2 // region of Cognito identity pool
            );

            ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory();
            {
                factory.region("US_WEST_2");
                factory.credentialsProvider(credenetialsProvider);
                factory.endpoint("ENDPOINT");
            }


                try {
                    final RecoveryAsAServiceClient client = factory.build(RecoveryAsAServiceClient.class);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    landingPageTextView.setText("PROXY ERROR");
                    Log.i(e.toString()));
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried doing the factory.build() call from an AsyncTask?

Comment: The error you are seeing is probably from the log line. Try using ```Log.e(e)``` instead to better understand the error

Comment: @CFL_Jeff, I'm sorry but what does the AsyncTask do? I tried to encompass it, but it did not change anything.

Comment: @jny This error persisted prior to including the Log statement. I inserted that in debug attempts, but I was not able to find anything useful.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Can you try this: factory.region(Regions.US_WEST_2); ?

Comment: @ChristopheBrown Did you finally resolve the issue? I'm currently facing the same issue here and I have no idea how to fix this..

Comment: @Bem It's hard to recall exactly what I did here. I believe what happened after this was that my team and I looked into HTTP requests for network connections and proceeded from there. If that doesn't help with your issue, double check your file system hierarchy and make sure you have everything in the right place.

Comment: @ChristopheBrown I checked everything and it seems like everything is setup correctly.. What do you suggest me to do now?

Comment: @ChristopheBrown Alright I solved it!